# Why is this button causing my layout to break?

Tags: css, button

I modified this CSS button to to put on my company's website but every time I try to implement it it causes the whole website to lose it's center alignment.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="contain">
<button class="support"> </button>
```

​

Here is the CSS:

```
    button.support {
background: rgb(38,128,195); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(38,128,195,1) 11%, rgba(30,101,155,1) 99%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(11%,rgba(38,128,195,1)), color-stop(99%,rgba(30,101,155,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(38,128,195,1) 11%,rgba(30,101,155,1) 99%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(38,128,195,1) 11%,rgba(30,101,155,1) 99%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(38,128,195,1) 11%,rgba(30,101,155,1) 99%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(38,128,195,1) 11%,rgba(30,101,155,1) 99%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2680c3', endColorstr='#1e659b',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
border-top: 1px solid #38538C;
border-right: 1px solid #1F2D4D;
border-bottom: 1px solid #151E33;
border-left: 1px solid #1F2D4D;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-box-shadow:  0 6px 0px #1F3053, 0 8px 4px 1px #111;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0 #1d2c4d, 0 6px 0px #1f3053, 0 8px 4px 1px #111111;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 0 #1D2C4D, 0 6px 0px #1F3053, 0 8px 4px 1px #111;
color: white;
font: bold 20px "helvetica neue", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
line-height: 1;
margin-bottom: 10px;
padding: 10px 0 12px 0;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: 0px -1px 1px #1E2D4D;
height: 175px;
width: 175px;
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
transition: all 200ms;
-moz-transition: all 200ms; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition: all 200ms; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: all 200ms; /* Opera */
}

button.support:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0px 20px 1px #87adff, 0px 1px 0 #1d2c4d, 0 6px 0px #1f3053, 0 8px 4px 1px #111111;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0px 20px 1px #87adff, 0px 1px 0 #1d2c4d, 0 6px 0px #1f3053, 0 8px 4px 1px #111111;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0px 20px 1px #87adff, 0px 1px 0 #1d2c4d, 0 6px 0px #1f3053, 0 8px 4px 1px #111111;
    cursor: pointer; }

  button.support:active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 10px 1px #5c8bee, 0 1px 0 #1d2c4d, 0 2px 0 #1f3053, 0 4px 3px 0 #111111;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 10px 1px #5c8bee, 0 1px 0 #1d2c4d, 0 2px 0 #1f3053, 0 4px 3px 0 #111111;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 10px 1px #5c8bee, 0 1px 0 #1d2c4d, 0 2px 0 #1f3053, 0 4px 3px 0 #111111;
    margin-top: 4px; }
​
```

I've tried changing it from an input to a hyperlink but it doesn't change anything, as soon as I add the CSS code it undoes all the horizontal alignment on the page. I'm ont seeing anything that should mess with it though.

It's somehow getting rid of the #site div. I'm not sure why it's doing that...

This is the page I'm trying to implement it on: http://bluebeam.com/us/support/

Comment: Are you closing the div that contains the button?

Comment: have you tried to remove all the borders and such?  I opened that site and I can't tell what button you are talking about?   do you have a test site where you can show the problem?

Comment: Yes, the html above got cut off somehow. I don't even have to add the html into the code to break the site, I just add the css without any html addressing it and it overwrites the #site CSS for some reason.

Comment: I do but it's local and I don't want to upload it to the live page because it literally breaks every single page if I even add the css code.

Comment: Are you aware that the global header has a class of support as well?

Comment: I wasn't aware actually. Adding the code in one line at a time seemed to have fixed the issue. I also changed the class so it doesn't conflict with the global header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is solved, but here is the reason you were having this issue: you had an invisible special character after the last closing brace on your CSS, specifically, a zero-width space ([U+200B](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm)).

Comment: Interesting. How does one find things like this?

Comment: Your own answer made me think of that. To confirm, I copied your code (from the "edit" textarea) and pasted into a text editor, then turned on the option to show invisible characters (I used TextMate).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Not really sure WHY but adding in the CSS line by line made it so it didn't break. I also changed the class name to support_btn to make sure it didn't conflict with the Global header, though it was fixed by this point.

I did exclude a few lines that I didn't need:

```
text-align: center;
text-shadow: 0px -1px 1px #1E2D4D;
color: white;
font: bold 20px "helvetica neue", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
```

But I can't really see how those would make a difference.