# New line in page for no reason

Tags: html, css

I have updated my banners in  my [site](http://www.s-maof.com/Forum/forum.php).
There are unexplainable over margins (between the first from the left and the second from the left.)
The margin is a new line in the HTML, but without any fader element to hold it.
It's weird.

I have tried to set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/opmaster/L3j98/4/), but the error does not exist there.

Here is the code:

```
<br>
<div class="invisible_box">
    <a class="overlay" onclick="window.open('http://www.s-maof.com/LandingPages/PRO/','PRO','scrollbars=yes, toolbar=no,status=no, width=570,height=650')"></a>
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://s-maof.com/stuff/bannerPro150x75.swf" width="150" height="75">
        <param name="movie" value="http://s-maof.com/stuff/bannerPro150x75.swf" />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        <param name="loop" value="false" />
    </object>
</div>

<div class="invisible_box" style="z-index: 7000">
    <a class="overlay" style="cursor:auto;"></a>
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://s-maof.com/stuff/tachlit-150x150.swf" width="150" height="150">
        <param name="movie" value="http://s-maof.com/stuff/tachlit-150x150.swf" />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        <param name="loop" value="false" />
   </object>               
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.invisible_box {
    height: 75px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
}
.overlay {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
    display: block;
    height: 75px;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 150px;
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have three invisible [`U+200B`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) characters after the div, and they may be the cause. The source code shows this (look in a text editor that allows you to see those):

```
<div class="invisible_box">
    <a class="overlay" onclick="window.open('http://www.s-maof.com/LandingPages/PRO/','PRO','scrollbars=yes, toolbar=no,status=no, width=570,height=650')"></a>
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://s-maof.com/stuff/bannerPro150x75.swf" width="150" height="75">
        <param name="movie" value="http://s-maof.com/stuff/bannerPro150x75.swf" />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        <param name="loop" value="false" />
    </object>
</div>​​​<U+200B><U+200B><U+200B>
```

They may be causing the rogue element you see on Chrome Console, as pointed out by Tiby.

Comment: Curiously, I happened to have added a [question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12719859/825789) about that yesterday.

Comment: that's cool, how did you saw that there are special characters there? In fact, what program did you use? And is there any option in the chrome console?

Comment: ya this happens to me once when i copied the code from jsfiddle. From then I first copy the code in notepad++ then to my editor. good article. :)

Comment: @Tiby it happened to me before, and I've seen lots of questions about it here, as more people are pasting code from jsfiddle. That's why I decided to add that question and answer I linked too, hoping to help others.

Comment: @bfavaretto that's cool, thanks. Anyway, that's a weird behavior

Answer (score 3):

In the Google Chrome Console, if you take a look at that area, there is a large empty text block between the first banner and the second one (it appears between quotes). I just deleted that and the empty space between the two banners disappeared. Try it out.

Comment: I know. I have stated that in the question. what could be the cause for that?? and why doesn't it appear in the jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2):

try to insert the html comment in there `<!--  -->`

```
<div class="invisible_box">
            <a class="overlay" onclick="window.open('http://www.s-maof.com/LandingPages/PRO/','PRO','scrollbars=yes, toolbar=no,status=no, width=570,height=650')"></a>
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://s-maof.com/stuff/bannerPro150x75.swf" width="150" height="75">
                <param name="movie" value="http://s-maof.com/stuff/bannerPro150x75.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
                <param name="loop" value="false" />
            </object>
        </div><!--

                --><div class="invisible_box" style="z-index: 7000">
<a class="overlay" style="cursor:auto;"></a>
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://s-maof.com/stuff/tachlit-150x150.swf" width="150" height="150">
        <param name="movie" value="http://s-maof.com/stuff/tachlit-150x150.swf" />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        <param name="loop" value="false" />
   </object>      

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys and @Mr_Green,

There were hidden three characters that were discovered only when I copied the code to notepad!! there were NOT shown in the vbulletin editor (my site's framework).

very interesting..