# Bootstrap tooltips defy me

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I am following [the documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips) as closely as I can, but I can't get the tooltips working. What am I doing wrong?

I've tried a lot of things. Here is some of what I've tried in a sample file.

http://anunexpectacle.com/micros/

I'm pretty desperate now. Please sort me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your selector is wrong.  When I used this, the tooltips appeared:

```
$("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip();
```

Note that `$("tooltip")` looks for HTML tags like `<tooltip>something</tooltip>`, but in this case (I guess) you mean to target the links, which have the attribute `rel=tooltip`.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion in this new file to no avail: http://anunexpectacle.com/micros/index2.html

The selector I've used is copied direct from the docs. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @KindOfGuy bizarre ... I copied your files locally, and the tooltips work for me in Chrome.  Your page is showing this `Unexpected token ILLEGAL` error message that I don't understand, which I suppose may be the cause.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719859/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-illegal

Comment: @KindOfGuy there's something going on with your file's encoding.  I'd try copy/pasting the whole thing to a new file, and making sure to save it with UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: I got rid of that: http://anunexpectacle.com/micros/index3.html Still doesn't work for me, nor locally, nor online. Thanks for trying. Any more thoughts?

Comment: @KindOfGuy the error is fixed, but now the selector is back to `$("tooltip")` -- try changing back to my suggestion above.

Comment: Yes, I just saw that. Thanks for persisting. I have no idea where that encoding error came from. This has been one of those grotesque bugs where Satan was overseeing my 'progress'. It took a miracle to get me out of there. You were that miracle. Thank you again

Comment: Ha, glad I could help.  There will always be those random pull-your-hair-out moments in programming ...