# What is causing these JavaScript errors when using jQuery's filter() inside a namespace?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, filter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719859/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-illegal)

Can someone tell me why these errors are occurring and what to do to fix them?

```
/*global $:false */

Blah.BlahBlah = {
  findLinks : function () {
    "use strict";

    $('a').filter(function () {
      return !(/https?:\/\/[^\/]*xyz.*/i.test($(this).attr('href')));
    }).text("***");
  ​}
};
```

Throws these errors in JSHint :

- Line 10: ​} Unexpected '​'.
- Line 11: }; Expected '}' to match '{' from line 3 and instead saw ';'.
- Line 11: }; Missing semicolon.

Chrome console shows this error:

- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

However, using this code ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dgy6T/)) in an encapsulated anonymous function does not throw an error:

```
/*global $:false */

(function() {

  "use strict";

  $('a').filter(function() {
    return !(/https?:\/\/[^\/]*xyz.*/i.test($(this).attr('href')));
  }).text("***");

}());
```

Comment: Jsfiddle copies an illegal character when you do a straight copy-paste from their site... Open your inspector in chrome and you'll see it.

Comment: The first example appears to work fine in the Google Chrome console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I pasted your first fragment into jsbin and I saw a strange character before the second-to-last close brace `}`... possibly a normally non-printable character?

Comment: I see what you mean. The character has been removed.

Comment: @Cofey, it seems that you stated that that wasn't the problem so soon then