# strange javascript error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719859/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-illegal)

I was working 2hours aho and now I comeback on my code and I have in chrome console

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

in my function.js

I only have:

```
function test(){
    alert("aa")​
}
```

I also have an error on firefox

Thanks

Comment: Statements *should* end with `;` shouldn't they?

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/gAvb3/

Comment: @JanDvorak JSLint your fiddle. Maybe ant's doctype is strict

Comment: @Swadq two missing semicolons and one implied global. Nothing serious.

Comment: Using semi-colons or not depends what [philosophy you want to follow](http://es5.github.com/#x7.9). In my case, I always use them

Comment: Ok thanks this is due to a past from chrome

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look what I found:

[image]

Looks like you have an illegal character right after the closing parenthesis. I don't know how that got there, but deleting it should make it work.

Comment: I couldn't confirm this in Chrome.

Comment: I think you're right, when I look sthe source code I have â€‹ just after my alert I use eclipse and can't remove it maybe an encode problem

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your original source for trailing white-space characters, and add a line-terminator after the alert call. The semi-colons are optional, but it's best to include them really.

```
function test()
{
    alert('aa');//<-- check for trailing white-space here
}//<-- and here, too
```

Answer (score 0):

Retype the code instead of copy paste, there might be some invisible characters in the code.