# Strange JQuery error

Tags: jquery

Please take a look at my website and open browser console for error check: http://mayy.in/stp.html

I am looking at it in Chrome console and its giving me error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

on line 44

What could be the problem? Its a very simple piece of code like this:

```
$('div').each("click", function() {

$(this).remove();​​​​​​​
});​
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719859/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-illegal

Comment: Can someone pleasse explain to me why people are clickin the close button

Comment: Because this is a duplicate. Read the other question. Even if it weren't a duplicate, the moment you fix the web page the question becomes meaningless so it's too localized.

Comment: Also, in addition to the other answers, you will need to place your code in `.ready()` for this to work correctly.

Comment: @Juhana  is right in this question is a duplicate, just replace $(this).remove; and the following line to get rid of the invisible characters.

Comment: Oke will do that, still dont see why it has to be closed..

Comment: @Lee Taylor Really...are you serious

Comment: Paste your js into http://jsbin.com/, you'll see the invisible characters show up as red dots.

Comment: @Youss You're saying your question is closed?

Comment: @Jeff Steil I already did

Comment: This will help you 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/12719860/1391805

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think your code is correct. You can bind event on all element without iterating.
through each.

I debugged your code and found there are some special characters in your code [image]

I was able to run code after Removing ';' .

```
$('div').click( function() {

$(this).remove();​​​​​​​
});​
```

OR

$('div').on('click', function() {

```
$(this).remove();​​​​​​​
});​
```

Comment: That's irrelevant at this stage, OP sees syntax error.

Comment: Still giving me the same error...

Comment: @Jack, I mentioned the reason of error.