# Escape \u200b (Zero width space) and other illegal JavaScript characters

Tags: javascript, escaping

I have a set of JavaScript objects I bootstrap to a backend template to initialise my Backbone.js collections on page load. It looks something like this (as Twig template):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
    var jobCollection = new App.Collections.Item(
        {% for item in items %}
        {
            name: '{{ item.name }}',
            ...
        },
        {% endfor %}
    );
})();
</script>
```

The problem I'm having is that some text fields contain \u200b (Zero width space) that break the JavaScript.

What is the best way to escape these characters? Should I escape them in the backend (I'm using Symfony 2 with Twig to render the initial template) or should I escape them on the client with JavaScript? How can I escape the zero width space character and others in JavaScript or PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the character only appears inside strings, either escaped as `\u200b` or as literals, you should be fine. They're only illegal as identifiers. And even as identifiers, you could still use them as object property names, if you use subscript notation (`obj["aaa\u200b"] = "foo"`); at least in Chrome, but I'm not sure how safe/compatible that is.

Look at a few example that seem to work:

```
var escaped = "aaa \u200b bbb";
var unescaped = "bbb ​ ccc";

console.log(escaped.charCodeAt(4));
console.log(unescaped.charCodeAt(4));

var obj = {};
obj[escaped] = "foo";
obj[unescaped] = "bar";
console.log(obj[escaped]);
console.log(obj[unescaped]);
console.log(obj["aaa \u200b bbb"]);
console.log(obj["bbb ​ ccc"]);
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JqjEK

You might also be interested on this Q/A I wrote a while ago: [No visible cause for "Unexpected token ILLEGAL"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719859/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-illegal/12719860#12719860)

Comment: Thanks for the gerate answer! I found out the there also was a line break in the string I set for `name` and directly afterwards was the Escape \u200b causing the errors. So I actually have to escape for line breaks, not the Escape character as you explained in the answer.

Comment: Makes sense, glad you're able to figure it out!