# javascript confirm box is not working

Tags: javascript, confirm

this is my code

```
 $('#Cancel').click(function() {

        var baseurl     = ' <?php echo $this->strBaseUrl?>';
        var cancel_msg  = " <?php echo Messageclass::setMessage('CAN01')?>";

        var where_to = confirm(cancel_msg);
        if (where_to == true){
            return true;
        }else{
            location.href = "";
        }

    });
```

but there is an error showing below the variable cancel_msg. the error is

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

the php logic is working perfectly. if any one know about this please help me

thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719859/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-illegal

Comment: What does `Messageclass::setMessage('CAN01')` return? Perhaps something containing a quotation mark? Also, don’t write `== true`. It’s redundant.

Comment: what is being outputted by Messageclass::setMessage('CAN01')? Anything with double quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what setMessage outputs, but that error is referring to an illegal character. This could be a newline character but is more likely a double quote:

`var cancel_msg  = " <?php echo addslashes(Messageclass::setMessage('CAN01'))?>";`

also, you could reduce your function to:

`return window.confirm(cancel_msg);`

Comment: Why specify `window`, out of curiosity? Also, there’s still the `location.href = "";` to consider…

Comment: because old habits die hard, I only seem to do that with alert, prompt and confirm. Anyway, you are right about the `location.href = ""` part.