# Wordpress & Javascript: String variable having html tags being read by browser with newline character

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have gone crazy trying to resolve this issue.

In my javascript code I have am defining a string variable in which I am putting an HTML table in the form of string.. i.e.:

```
var tData="<table><tbody><tr><a><th>Type</th><th>Score</th><th>Percentile</th></a></tr><tr><td><a>Overall</a></td><td>2.4</td><td>50%</td></tr><tr><td><a>Best 100</a></td><td>2.3</td><td>70%</td></tr></tbody></table>";
```

Now this variable assignment through the string is being read by my browser (both chrome and firefox) as an HTML code with line breaks. Take a look at the image below for more clarity.

The code works fine if I remove html tags and write a simple string. So I can assure you there are no previous inverted comma errors (i checked them multiple times) and no bogus characters.

[image]

I have spent too many hours on this issue. Please please help me on this.

**EDIT**

Added Wordpress in title and Tags as this is a wordpress issue.

Comment: What's the doctype of the page? If it is XHTML, you have to wrap the code in a `CDATA` declaration.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle demonstrating your problem (for example on http://jsbin.com) ?

Comment: Is that literally what that line is?

Comment: @FelixKling The top of the doc in source code shows following: 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy.... Yes thats it... nothing more , nothing less

Comment: it seems you write this code in multiline in your image.

Comment: @dystroy: Code works fine in fiddle :(

Comment: @user1517108 Yes, because the doctype isn't the same. See Felix's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your document is XHTML, you have to enclose your code into a CDATA section:

```
<script>
<![CDATA[
    // code here
]]>
</script>
```

This prevents the browser from interpreting `<...>` sequences in the content as tags.

Comment: +1 An alternative being to change the doctype to HTML if XHTML isn't really needed.

Comment: @user1517108 Can you link to an (as minimal as possible) online example  ?

Comment: @dystroy: My fiddle at http://jsbin.com/ezical/2/edit The fiddle works fine. My site at http://www.ahead.freeiz.com/ . This doesnt work fine.

Comment: @dystroy: Btw the minimal code pasted in fiddle does not work in the website with the var tData code.

Comment: @dystroy: I also changed to a theme with <!DOCTYPE html> but got the same error.

Comment: @dystroy: Have you caught the error? Please can you paste a solution. I am not a progarmmer and am more of a part-time researcher... would appreciate if you can post explanatory answer. Thanks

Comment: @dystroy: But i dont want multiline string literal. Check the fiddle code. I want it in one line only. Nonetheless I had tried multiline before as well... It is not helpful as anyways the code gives me error the moment the inverted commas start ans <table> begins. So I get error before the '\' symbol.

Comment: @user1517108: The browser does not recognize the CDATA section properly because the end is `//]]&gt;` where it should be `//]]>`. Don't encode the `>`. If you fix this, it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want multiline strings in JavaScript, you have to unescape the newline, ie

```
var str = "abc\
de";
```

Comment: But the OP doesn't want to have a multiline string.

Comment: The OP posted his code at he beginning of the post, it's all in one line.

Comment: @FelixKling: Btw the minimal code pasted in fiddle does not work in the website with the var tData code.

Comment: I want a single line only... do not want multiline.. but the browser is interpreting it as multiline which I do not want. Moreover the error occurs at the start of the <table> tag, so even if when I use \ , it doesnt help as the error will occur before the symbol is parsed.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Eureka!!!

I found a get around. I broke the following string :

```
var tData="<table><tbody><tr><a><th>Type</th><th>Score</th><th>Percentile</th></a></tr><tr><td><a>Overall</a></td><td>2.4</td><td>50%</td></tr><tr><td><a>Best 100</a></td><td>2.3</td><td>70%</td></tr></tbody></table>";
```

into

```
  var tData = "<tab"+"le><tb"+"ody><t"+"r><a><t"+"h>Type</t"+"h><t"+"h>Score</t"+"h><t"+"h>Percentile</t"+"h></a></t"+"r><t"+"r><t"+"d><a>Overall</a></t"+"d><t"+"d>2.4</t"+"d><t"+"d>50%</t"+"d></t"+"r><t"+"r><t"+"d><a>Best 100</a></t"+"d><t"+"d>2.3</t"+"d><t"+"d>70%</t"+"d></t"+"r></tbo"+"dy></ta"+"ble>";
```

to fool the browser. I am still hoping for a better answer please.

Answer (score 0):

```
Delete all invisible characters (whitespace) around that area,
then give it another try.
```

Try this:

```
var tData="<table><tbody>";
tData+="<tr><th><a>Type</a></th><th>Score</th><th>Percentile</th></tr>";
tData+="<tr><td><a>Overall</a></td><td>2.4</td><td>50%</td></tr>";
tData+="<tr><td><a>Best 100</a></td><td>2.3</td><td>70%</td></tr>";
tData+="</tbody></table>";
```

Possible Duplicate [No visible cause for "Unexpected token ILLEGAL"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719859/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-illegal)

Comment: I changed my answer, test it.

Comment: Nopes... doesnt help. Basically the error comes in first line's first word after the inverted commas. So the  <table> starts from a new line as the browser parses it as html instead of a string. Pls check my answer I just pasted and it will provide some clarity.