# jQuery Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL error on page load in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, popupwindow

As the question speaks itself I am having trouble using jQuery as even the simple functions are throwing `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` on Page load and I don't have enough knowledge of jQuery to solve such problems myself.

here are the details:

1. Library on page head:

   ```
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   ```
2. jQuery popupwindow function:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">    
           $(document).ready(function() {
              $('#<%=_btstrtTest.ClientID %>').click(function() {
                var NWin = window.open($(this).prop('href'), 'height=800,width=800');
                if (window.focus) 
                {<br/>
                  NWin.focus();
                }<br/>
                return false;
               });
           });​
       </script>
   ```

FYI: I am not using ASP.Net MVC, just plain ASP.Net with C# and the head is coming from master page while the function is in `Contentplaceholder` of the `home.aspx` page if that helps.

Thanks

Comment: Please read [FAQ] for how to format your question..

Comment: thanks i am just having a Bad connection today, i know how to format the question, but i had trouble submitting the data @SonerGönül

Comment: You can check here for your problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719859/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-illegal

Comment: indeed it was because i copied the functions from jsfiddle and it added hidden Unicodes in syntax, thank you very much @OzanDeniz

Comment: are you importing jquery twice in the page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete all invisible characters (whitespace) around that area, then give it another try.

I've seen that error in Safari when copy/pasting code. You can pick up some invalid (and unfortunately invisible) characters.

Used to happen to me a lot when copying from jsFiddle.

and add single jQuery Library file either full or min

Comment: I had the exact same issue. It wasn't whitespace, but extra characters like this..... OnClientClick="ClosePopup('ModalWindowLP');();". I removed the (); and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semicolon before the last one.

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
        $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#<%=_btstrtTest.ClientID %>').click(function() {
             var NWin = window.open($(this).prop('href'), 'height=800,width=800');
             if (window.focus) 
             {<br/>
               NWin.focus();
             }<br/>
             return false;
            })
        });​
    </script>
```