# Uglify with r.js throws a parsing error

Tags: requirejs, js-amd, uglifyjs, r.js

I'm using r.js to optimize/uglify my JavaScript code which is using RequireJS.

One of my modules is a polyfill module:

```
define(function(){
    if (!Array.prototype.filter)
    {  /* ... */ }

    var isPolyfillNeeded = function () { /* ... */ }

    if (isPolyfillNeeded()) {
        /* polyfill implementation */
    }
});
```

The module causes parsing error thrown from r.js when trying to uglify it, saying:

```
Tracing dependencies for: ../scripts/main-app
Error: Parse error using UglifyJS for file: C:/.../polyfill.js
Unexpected character '?' (line: .., col: .., pos: ..)

undefined
In module tree:
    ../scripts/main-main-app
      moduleA
        moduleB
```

When replacing `var isPolyfillNeeded = function ()` with `function isPolyfillNeeded()`, it works fine.
Why is that?

Comment: What does the body of that function look like?

Comment: @Blender apparently I had a bad character hiding somewhere (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719859/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-illegal). I still can't explain why the var-function change solved it, but anyway - removing a bad character fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was a bad character that was hiding somewhere in my code, as I copy pasted from some snippet. It was invisible so it was hard to spot.