# Why is this postMessage/receiveMessage not working?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I am trying to use postMessage/receiveMessage to access the response of a cross-domain request via an iframe.

The iframe calls a resource which usually does a particular operation, but when there is an error it instead responds with a script snippet that calls postMessage.

This was working in development environment but in production it fails and I guess it has something to do with HTTPS but not sure how to resolve it.

The response code looks like this:

```
<script>
$.postMessage(whateverData, 'https://abc.def.com', parent );
</script>
```

The receive message on the client looks like this:

```
$.receiveMessage(function(e){       
            alert(e.data);
        }, 'http://blah123');
```

The error I am seeing in console (Chrome browser) looks like this: (which displays the HTTP request URL)

```
The page at https://abc.def.com/xyz/something.html#jkl displayed insecure content from http://blah123/sub/qwerty/target.aspx?parmsRemoved
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

What went wrong here? How to fix?

Edit: Hmm, is it possible that the first console message is misleading - that is has nothing to do with security but that the error is it is having trouble parsing the text inside of my 'whateverData' var?

Answer (score 0):

Those are 2 separated issues.

- You display http content inside of https page.
- Invalid character on the page: [No visible cause for "Unexpected token ILLEGAL"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719859/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-illegal).

And for post/receiveMessage, they have slightly different restrictions in different browsers depending on protocol (`file://`, `https://`, `http://`), so pay attention to that too.