# Button functions in jsfiddle but does not clear ordered list in text editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, jsfiddle

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aFeyy/15/)

I have written a short script that takes the pagex and pageY coordinates of a mouse click and appends them to a list. Everything functions except the button that is supposed to clear the list( a click appearing even when the clear button is pressed also happens but that is not an issue)

anyway I corrected some work in jsfiddle and everything works fine there, but when I made the the same corrections in notepad++ the button doesnt function at all. IE it does not clear the list, but when I click the same button in jsfiddle it works fine. Have tested on mozilla Chrome and IE

```
         <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Click Away</title>
    <link href="stylesheets/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>


        $(document).click(function(e){
            $("#coordList").append("<li>"+ "pageX: " + e.pageX + ",    pageY: " + e.pageY +"</li>"); 
        });

        $("#clear").click(function() {
            $("#coordList").empty();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
            <h1> Coordinates </h1>
        </header>
        <button id="clear"> Clear list </button>
        <div id="list"> 
            <ol id="coordList"></ol>
              </div>
            </div>
              </body>
                  </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just learnt this five minutes ago. [`event.stopPropagation();`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) stops the event from triggering that of it's parents, including the `body` element. Like this:

```
$("#clear").click(function (event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $("#coordList").empty();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Sg7VQ/3/)

Comment: This works great. For some reason the code still does not work outside of JSfiddle so my problem lies somewhere else. Perhaps an invisible character? I'll just do a clean rewrite and see what happens

Comment: just rewrote it and it still doesnt function outside of jssfiddle. Hmmm. I tried it with FF and chrome so far

Comment: A possible problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719859/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-illegal

Comment: Does it work in chrome and Mozilla? Any errors in console in IE?

Comment: No errors in any browser, everything works except for the button. this is for an assignment so I'll just link the jsfiddle to my professor instead. I'm sure he'll accept it