# Javascript: Weird illegal character error on a if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, character

I've been struggling with a strange syntax error since yesterday: The FF debugger keeps saying "SyntaxError: illegal character" at this specific line :

```
function newTimePeriod(ID, param, paramID, unit)
{
    updateSession();
    //check if date
    //(I got this regex from another post)
    var re = new RegExp("^\\d{4,4}(-\\d{1,2}){1,2}( \\d{1,2}(:\\d{1,2}){1,2})?$");

    var dateFrom = document.getElementById("chart_date_min_" + ID).value;
    var dateTo = document.getElementById("chart_date_max_" + ID).value;
    var fromCorrect = re.test(dateFrom);  
    var toCorrect = re.test(dateFrom);  
    /**/if (fromCorrect && toCorrect)​{/**/   //return illegal character
    LoadGraph(ID, param, paramID, unit, dateFrom, dateTo);
    }
}
```

I tried to include this script into the main php page, or separate it; it doesn't change a thing. Charset used is UTF-8, and fromCorrect and toCorrect returns booleans correctly (the regex is working)

When I remove the if statement the script is loading...
Notepad++ doesn't show any special characters hiding anywhere.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I think/hope OP added the ** to show which line the error is in.

Comment: Can you also provide the html for this specially dateFrom and dateTo

Comment: There is an invisible space between `)` and `{`. Delete the line and re-write it (*don't* copy-paste).

Comment: possible duplicate of [SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719859/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-illegal)

Comment: If you are interested in what non-printable character caused the error, then you could copy the line in question into a HEX editor. The HEX view of (g)vim is quite helpful for those kinds of problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have copied your code into a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/janfoeh/s6VFs/) - seems you have a [zero-width space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) between the braces:

```
if (fromCorrect && toCorrect)​{
                             ^
```

Answer (score 3):

The good way to solve weird characters creeping in from copying and pasting is to manually re-type the line in question.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly now! I though notepad++ was able to display such characters...