# Monogdb undefined error.. one doc is inserted and another doc is not inserted

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to insert two documents in to a collection called **hi**.
Hear one document is inserted and other one is not inserting..
for understanding i keep the values as **blue** and **red** for **pp** field.
when i am inserting blue its inserted.
and when i insert red its not inserted

```
db.hi.insert({city:"ny",pp:"blue"})
```

this doc is inserted
if in this place and in this doc if i changed pp field to red or any thing its inserted

```
db.hi.insert({city:"ny",pp:"red"})
```

this doc is not inserted

but in this place if i changed it to blue or any thing also it wont insert

may be some thing like place holder s some thing i don't know what is this.. that's why i make a video for this ..

very STRANGE..
**i made a video(recorded).. please watch in mute and in HD**
**and i know if you tried in you system it will work but for me its not worked .. that's why i make a video**

**Hear is the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q5xyKx9k0_c) i uploaded.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an **invisible character** in the code, right after the semicolon. It's the Unicode `U+200B Zero-width` space character. Instead of pressing "up" on your keyboard, try writing the insert statement again from scratch.

See also: [No visible cause for "Unexpected token ILLEGAL"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719859/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-illegal)