# Php Javascript Variable Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest, youtube-api, str-replace

I have this PHP code, which try to get the description of a YouTube channel, and run it in a JS file (xhr_object), and I've got this error : Unexpected token ILLEGAL.
But I found the problem : $channel_descr contains a simple quote in somes cases, which break the JS code. I've already tried to use str_replace() but it doesn't change anything..

```
$json = file_get_contents("...?alt=json&part=snippet");
$data = json_decode($json, true);

$channel_descr = $data['entry']['content']['$t'];
$channel_descr = str_replace("\"", "&sbquo;", $channel_descr);
echo "alert (".$channel_descr.");";
```

Thanks.

EDIT

```
echo "alert ('".$channel_descr."');"; //Same Error
```

Comment: you'll need quotes around `$channel_descr`

Comment: I've tested this. Same error : Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719859/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-illegal can be tricky..

Comment: It might help be helpful to encode the string with `htmlentities` in PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: I finally found a solution : str_replace("\n", " ", $channel_descr);
Thanks to all :)