# jQuery unexpected token illegal for \n

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, newline

Any time I use `\n` anywhere in javascript/jQuery the browser throws

> uncaught syntaxerror: unexpected token illegal

I found ways to work around adding new lines without using `\n`, but I can't find a work around to read the `\n` from a textarea without using `\n`. I am using a mac pro mavericks with the chrome browser version 36. The code is output from a php script from a linux server. I have also tried in firefox and get an equivilent error.
Examples include:

```
var line = $('#textareaid').val().split("\n");
var line = $('#textareaid').val().split("\r\n");
var some = "This is\nsome text";
```

All of the examples have the error as well as any other use of `\n`. I have been unable to find any reference to `\n` not working, but plenty of examples of its use.

Comment: Try `.split("\\n")` and `.split("\\r\\n")`

Comment: `\n` should be 100% valid.

Comment: @epascarello True, I've never had a problem with it before. Just speculating.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719859/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-illegal)

Comment: I'm guessing that PHP is printing actual line breaks, not literally as above. So \\n would be correct at the PHP level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this-

```
var line = $('#textareaid').val().split("\\n");
```

Comment: This is exactly how I did it and now works. I thought I had tried like this before, but the doctype was messing it up. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with "\n" in JavaScript, but if your PHP is script is printing literal line breaks, your JavaScript will be invalid.

This PHP:

```
echo "split(\"\n\")";
```

Will print this:

```
split("
")
```

Which would raise a JavaScript syntax error.

So the PHP should be:

```
echo "split(\"\\n\")";
```

Comment: I had tried the double slash before, but I was in doctype which is why it didn't work. Works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As '\n' is an escape sequence so you have to use an additional backslash as shown below:

```
$('#textareaid').val().split("\\n");
```