# Display popup to user in asp.net application (popup from local application is displayed contrary to popup from server deployed application)

Tags: c#, asp.net, popup

I am developping an asp.net application. When an user clicks on a button, he calls a webservice passing also the parameter he has before entered in a textfield. When the webservice returns no results, it displays a popup, everything works well in local, but when I deploy my application on my windows server, the pop up is not displayed. This is my code:

```
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox.text))
        {
            try
            {
               //webservice call
               string result = webservice.function(textbox.text);
            }
            catch (SoapException ex)
            {
                Utils.Log_File(ex.Message);
                Utils.Log_File(ex.StackTrace);
                string message = ex.Message;
                //this popup is not working on the deployed application
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "error from code behind", string.Format("alert('{0}')", message), true);
            }
        }
```

I debug my code from client side in chrome to see the error.
When I debug the localhost everything works well, the popup  from soapexception is displayed with this message '[E_E1] [Parameter NotFound]'

When I debug the server app, I am getting this error in chrome console :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
alert('System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: [E_E1] [Parameter NotFound]
    [uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token illegal]
....
```

Comment: Is it possible that the call to Utils.Log_File results in an error when not running locally?

Comment: Did not think to that, I will try it and tell you.

Comment: Emil, I change the code by putting the generation of the message before the utils.log_file and it didn't change anything.

Comment: I also add some informations on my bug.

Comment: See this answer for an explanation of the error you're getting. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719859/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-illegal Still doesn't explain why it works locally though. I hope you find the cause. :)

Comment: Thanks I understand that's because of the message value. But I can't understand why the message value is different on the local app from the server app.

Answer (score -1):

Try using ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Error", "alert('"+MailMessage+"');");

Comment: what he is asking that this code is not working after deploying,and in your answer there is no changes in compare to his.

Comment: It's not an answer to my question, and this code is even not working on my local machine.

Comment: Acknowledged. The code is not correct also. Sorry for loss of your effort.