# Passing a parameter to function with single quote

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using this code segment

```
str += '<div class="section clear">' + 
    '<span><img src="' + pic_square + '" alt="" width="32px" height="32px" /></span>' + 
    '<span class="user_name">' + rows.data[i].name + '</span>' + 
    '<a href="#" class="blue_button blue_button_small flt_right" style="line-height: 16px; height: 18px; margin: 6px 15px 0 0;" onclick="showSelected(' + details + '); return false;">Select</a>' + 
'</div>';
```

Here details parameter may contain single quote.And I that case it is showing error.How can I solve this?

Comment: What error is appearing? By the way, you should probably turn the quotations around so that " wrap the strings meanwhile ' are used for the attribute values.

Comment: use " instead of '.  str += "" and not str += ''

Comment: the problem will be with the details variable. replace the `'` char to `\'`

Comment: Off topic - but a good demonstration of why mixing JS into HTML is generally best avoided

Answer (score 1):

Take all of your variables that may contain single quotes and apply the following to them:

```
str = str.replace(/(['"])/g, "\\$1");
```

That will escape all of your quotes.  Then you can use your variables in your function as is.

Or you can create a function to do this:

```
function escapeStrQuotes(str)
{
  return str.replace(/(['"])/g, "\\$1");
}
```

Then use like this:

```
str += '<div class="section clear">' + 
    '<span><img src="' + escapeStrQuotes(pic_square) + '" alt="" width="32px" height="32px" /></span>' + 
    '<span class="user_name">' + escapeStrQuotes(rows.data[i].name) + '</span>' + 
    '<a href="#" class="blue_button blue_button_small flt_right" style="line-height: 16px; height: 18px; margin: 6px 15px 0 0;" onclick="showSelected(' + escapeStrQuotes(details) + '); return false;">Select</a>' + 
'</div>';
```

Comment: Now it is showing

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: That sounds like an invisible character from a copy/paste that my can't see.  Try to remove code and add it back until you get that error.  Once  you identify the code, you may have to delete it and manually type it over.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719859/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-illegal

Answer (score 1):

Let jQuery do the heavy work of escaping variable contents instead:

```js
// for testing purposes
var pic_square = '#',
    rows = {
      data: [{name:'foo'}]
    },
    details = 'bla',
    i = 0;

function showSelected(details)
{
  alert(details);
}

$('<div class="section clear"> \
    <span><img alt="" width="32px" height="32px" /></span> \
    <span class="user_name"/> \
    <a href="#" class="blue_button blue_button_small flt_right" style="line-height: 16px; height: 18px; margin: 6px 15px 0 0;">Select</a> \
</div>')
  .find('img')
    .attr('src', pic_square)
    .end()
  .find('.user_name')
    .text(rows.data[i].name)
    .end()
  .find('a')
    .on('click', (function(details) {
      return function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        showSelected(details);
      };
    }(details)))
    .end()
  .appendTo('#container');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### This is EASY with jQuery!

All these blendings of HTML and Regex is just not good. You're using jQuery, just do it the jQuery way.

Also, I'm not sure why a parameter would ever have an apostrophe, but if it's value has one, then try using [**`.apply`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

Create your elements in your loops and assign info where it belongs. It's as simple as follows:

```
var details = rows.data[i].details, //  simply guessing at some form of how you got your param
    //  beging creating your elements. First, the div.section, which appears to be your wrapper, this will come into play later
    section = $('<div />', { class: 'section clear' }),
    //  now to create the image element. I know yours is wrapped in a span, but I'll show you a quick add for that a little later
    img = $('<img />', { alt: '', height: '32', src: pic_square, width: '32' }),
    //  now for your username span, I'm assuming this is your label
    userName = $('<span />', { class: 'user_name', text: rows.data[i].name }),
    //  here I create your link, notice I don't add the "onclick" method yet, just wait,
    //  going to show you use of apply
    lnkSelect = $('<a />', {
        class: 'blue_button blue_button_small flt_right',
        href: 'javascript:void(0)',
        style: 'line-height: 16px; height: 18px; margin: 6px 15px 0 0;',
        text: 'Select'
    });

//  Here is where it all comes together
//  jQuery's append/prepend methods are very powerful,
//  Notice you can join multiple elements in another with just simple comma separation,
//  You'll also notice that IMG span wrapper I was talking about earlier coming back!
section.append(
    //  First element in your div.section is the image, but alas! we need that SPAN tag around it!
    //  I simply use jQuery to create a SPAN tag and then append the image to it! Viola!
    $('<span />').append(img),
    //  Now to append that username span
    userName,
    //  finally, add the link clicker!
    lnkSelect
).appendTo($('body'));  //  this Trixy part is like "append", except it adds this element to whatever we pass in the selector! Thus, "appendTo"

//  Finally! The onclick value!
//  Since you mentioned some trixy stuff with the "details",
// I make use of ".apply", which you can pass parameters
//  through as a value in an array in the second param of apply
//  see more at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply
lnkSelect.on('click', function(e) { showSelected.apply(this, [details]) })
```

For a simple example, using your type of values and my code here, run the snippet below!

```js
$(function() {
 var pic_square = '../img/logo.png',
 rows = {
  data: [
   { name: 'Bob', details: "Bob'sPlace" },
   { name: 'Diana', details: "Diana's Shack" },
   { name: 'Jerry', details: "Jerry Atric's Mind Blowing" } ]
 },
 str = '';
 
 function showSelected(value) {
  alert(value);
 }
 
 $.each(rows.data, function(i) {
  var details = this.details,
   section = $('<div />', { class: 'section clear' }),
   img = $('<img />', { alt: '', height: '32', src: pic_square, width: '32' }),
   userName = $('<span />', { class: 'user_name', text: this.name }),
   lnkSelect = $('<a />', {
    class: 'blue_button blue_button_small flt_right',
    href: 'javascript:void(0)',
    style: 'line-height: 16px; height: 18px; margin: 6px 15px 0 0;',
    text: 'Select'
   });
  
  section.append(
   $('<span />').append(img),
   userName,
   lnkSelect
  ).appendTo($('#BODY')); // using a div with the id "BODY"
  
  lnkSelect.on('click', function(e) { showSelected.apply(this, [details]) })
 })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="BODY"></div>
```