# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL in dojo

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dojo

I wrote a upload script using dojo and form:

### HTML

```
<form action="/Form/Upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="FormId" method="post">                
<input id="..." name="..." type="file" onchange="UploadImage(this, FormId);" />
</form>
```

### Dojo

```
require([
    "dojo/dom-attr",
    "dojo/request/iframe"],
function (domattr, iframe) {
    UploadFile = function (Uploader, form) {
        if (Uploader.value != "") {
            if (Uploader.files[0].size < 50000000) {
                iframe(form.formAction, {
                    form: form,
                    handleAs: "text",
                    timeout: 20000,
                    method: "POST"
                }).then(function (name) {
                    .
                    .
                    .
                }, function (err) {
                    .
                    .
                    .
                });
            }
        }
    };
};
```

For some reason I get an error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

But this does not happen every time! After I refresh the page it sometimes works and some times gives an error. Then I run debugger in chrome it doesn't even get to dojo. It throws an error on the `<form>` row.  (all the dots is a irrelevant code because it doesn't get to that point when the error is thrown but is works perfectly after I refresh the page)

Comment: Remove your 3 dots after then() and function() ?

Comment: all the dots is a irrelevant code because it doesn't get to that point when the error is thrown but is works perfectly after I refresh the page

Comment: If there is a syntax error, it would be when the browser is parsing *all* of the code before *any* of it runs, so I wouldn't rule out any code as irrelevant.  Also, since you're saying it snags on the `<form>` line, maybe seeing the whole page source in context would be better.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing one ) at the end (for 'require')

```
});
```

Does this work? ofcourse without dots in this part:

```
}).then(function (name) {
                .
                .
                .
            }, function (err) {
                .
                .
                .
```

Also make sure there are no invisible weird chars in your text. They can be inserted by some apps (Aptana did this for me for instance).

Check this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719859/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-illegal) also.

Comment: The code works after I refresh the page. So I don't think that it could be this kind of error

Comment: I think my edited answer might help discovering whats bothering you