# How can I I pass "12mca22@nirmauni.ac.in" in ajax data field?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass `12mca22@nirmauni.ac.in` in ajax but it is giving me such error

`'unexpected Token Illegal.'`

how can I pass such a string in ajax?

this is My Code

```
$.ajax({
            url:'http://localhost/student',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                data:"12mca22@nirmauni.ac.in"
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you post some more code please? There is something else going on

Comment: instead of my string I have tried it with only 12mca22 then it worked but not with . and @

Comment: I am using phph there is no function like this

Comment: yeah but its not working dear

Comment: Try to find errors in some code before or after your `$.ajax`

Comment: Maybe related to invisible characters - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719859/no-visible-cause-for-unexpected-token-illegal

Answer (score 0):

Your string is perfectly fine, but jQuery's just throwing a fit because you've got an extra comma. Remove it:

```
data: {
    data:"12mca22@nirmauni.ac.in"
},
```

and you should be fine. jQuery expects the `data` field to contain a JSON object, so that extra comma there makes the JSON syntax invalid and it's unexpected, like the error message says

The below code executes fine.

```js
$.ajax({
    url:'http://httpbin.org/post',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        data:"12mca22@nirmauni.ac.in"
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xw4escqd/)

[image]

Comment: I am still facing the same problem they are not allowing me to add string having . and @

Comment: its not on comma iits due to . and @