# How to resolve JavaScript 'Unxpected Token Error'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle, jsbin

I have written some JavaScript code which, when run, produces the following error:

```
"error"
"SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

I don't know what does this error mean. I tried googling it but couldn't find anything useful.

Here's my code:

---

HTML:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#fostering').on('click', function(){
       $(this).animate({
           width : 50px;
       });
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> Something </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fostering"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

So,

- What's causing this error?
- How do I resolve it?

Comment: width : 50px;  remove the semicolon

Comment: The error is thrown because you don't put `50px` inside quotes. Also there shouldn't be a semicolon after `width: "50px"`

Comment: It's ok, well it arises when you have a character at a place where it shouldn't  be. Basicaly if you want to read more on how JS parses the given code then  here is a good article about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719859/no-visible-cause-for-unexpected-token-illegal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the semicolon and put it in a quotation (**width** attribute value):

```
  $('#fostering').on('click', function(){
     $(this).animate({
      width : "50px"
     });
    });
```

This error arises when you have a character at a place where it shouldn't be. Basically, if you want to read more on how JS parses the given code then here is a good article about it,

URL: [No visible cause for "Unexpected token ILLEGAL"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719859/no-visible-cause-for-unexpected-token-illegal)

Comment: Ah, I had forgotten to upvote your solution! Did it now. ;)