# SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL on comment with Web Component Tester

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, polymer-1.0, codeship, web-component-tester

I use Codeship to test [my project](https://github.com/TFarla/night-live) based on the [Polymer starter kit v1.1](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/releases/tag/v1.1.0).

When I run `npm test` inside the test pipeline I see the following error:

```
> @ test /home/rof/src/github.com/TFarla/night-live
> gulp test:local

/home/rof/src/github.com/TFarla/night-live/node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/lodash/index.js:8404
/**
^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:413:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/rof/src/github.com/TFarla/night-live/node_modules/browser-sync/lib/hooks.js:3:20)
at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Here are the setup commands:

```
# By default we use the Node.js version set in your package.json or the latest
# version from the 0.10 release
#
# You can use nvm to install any Node.js (or io.js) version you require.
nvm install 4.0
nvm use 4.0
npm install -g bower
npm install -g gulp
npm install && bower install
```

Anyone got a solution?

Edit:
Not sure if related but when Codeship executes `npm install` it outputs a lot of unmet dependencies.

```
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/rof/src/github.com/TFarla/night-live/node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/browser-sync-ui requires connect-history-api-fallback@'0.0.5' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/rof/src/github.com/TFarla/night-live/node_modules/connect-history-api-fallback,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.1.0
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/rof/src/github.com/TFarla/night-live/node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io requires debug@'1.0.3' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/rof/src/github.com/TFarla/night-live/node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/debug,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.1.0
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/rof/src/github.com/TFarla/night-live/node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-parser requires debug@'0.7.4' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/rof/src/github.com/TFarla/night-live/node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/debug,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.1.0
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/rof/src/github.com/TFarla/night-live/node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client requires debug@'0.7.4' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/rof/src/github.com/TFarla/night-live/node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/debug,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.1.0
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/rof/src/github.com/TFarla/night-live/node_modules/gulp-jshint/node_modules/jshint requires lodash@'3.7.x' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/rof/src/github.com/TFarla/night-live/node_modules/gulp-jshint/node_modules/lodash,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 3.10.1
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/rof/src/github.com/TFarla/night-live/node_modules/web-component-tester/node_modules/bower requires chalk@'^1.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/rof/src/github.com/TFarla/night-live/node_modules/web-component-tester/node_modules/chalk,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.5.1
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/rof/src/github.com/TFarla/night-live/node_modules/web-component-tester/node_modules/bower requires update-notifier@'^0.3.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/rof/src/github.com/TFarla/night-live/node_modules/web-component-tester/node_modules/update-notifier,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.5.0
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/rof/src/github.com/TFarla/night-live/node_modules/web-component-tester/node_modules/wd requires async@'~1.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/rof/src/github.com/TFarla/night-live/node_modules/web-component-tester/node_modules/async,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.9.2
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/rof/src/github.com/TFarla/night-live/node_modules/web-component-tester/node_modules/wd requires lodash@'~3.9.3' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/rof/src/github.com/TFarla/night-live/node_modules/web-component-tester/node_modules/lodash,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 3.10.1
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/rof/src/github.com/TFarla/night-live/node_modules/web-component-tester/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-parser requires debug@'0.7.4' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/rof/src/github.com/TFarla/night-live/node_modules/web-component-tester/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/debug,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.1.0
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/rof/src/github.com/TFarla/night-live/node_modules/web-component-tester/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client requires debug@'1.0.4' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/rof/src/github.com/TFarla/night-live/node_modules/web-component-tester/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/debug,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.7.4
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/rof/src/github.com/TFarla/night-live/node_modules/web-component-tester/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client requires parseuri@'0.0.4' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/rof/src/github.com/TFarla/night-live/node_modules/web-component-tester/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/parseuri,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.0.2
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/rof/src/github.com/TFarla/night-live/node_modules/web-component-tester/node_modules/wct-sauce/node_modules/request/node_modules/har-validator requires chalk@'^1.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /home/rof/src/github.com/TFarla/night-live/node_modules/web-component-tester/node_modules/chalk,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.5.1
```

Comment: Try running it in a Docker container and see if you can recreate the problem there: `docker run -it -v=$PWD/night-live:/usr/src/app -w=/usr/src/app --rm node:4.0 bash`

Comment: Are you transpiling your code with babel? What about your sourceMaps? Maybe they are broken for some reason and thats the reason you get the comment as the location for the error

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` is an error that you get where you try to require a JavaScript file is malformed. e.g: syntax error like any kind, like unbalanced braces, or whatever.

Comment: This may help you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719859/no-visible-cause-for-unexpected-token-illegal

Comment: Check Your gulpfile. Maybe it has some minifier running and creating the syntax errors has similar problems before because of this.

Answer (score 1):

After installing the dependencies, did you go inside the node modules directory and changed any of the lodash files ?

1. Here are some things you can try.
2. In your project dorectory, do `rm -r node-modules`. This will delete the node dependency directory.
3. Go to your package.json and check if the dependencies are deprecated; Check to see if they have newer version available on npm. If they do, update the package.json accordingly. (latest version for browser-sync is 2.18.13)
4. List item
5. Do `npm install`
6. Do `bower install`