# How to get back sitecore menu items?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

Once I deployed 'my' solution client once logged into sitecore cms can't see menu items?
See:
[image][image]

Client is furious(understandably), what can I do?

Marek brought to my attention that I should check browser for error messages which I did:[image]
Thanks Marek, it seems to be jquery conflict, right?
How come I didn't receive same error running same version locally?

edit 2:
Fixed the browser error by following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719859/no-visible-cause-for-unexpected-token-illegal), but problem still persists ...

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: yes, there are, it seems to be a jquery conflict, see new picture; but how come I don't have same issue locally ?

Comment: `Unexpected token` in `jquery-1.10.2.min.js`? Can you check what is the response of this file?

Comment: I found the solution on stack overflow that involves deleting some invisible characters at the end of the mentioned jquery file. That fixed browser error but problem still persists now with no error in browser console ...

Comment: This might be a long shot, but can you clear browser cache? also,are you getting any 404 responses in Network tab?

Comment: No, no 404 and cache & cookie cleaned ...

Comment: @krul Maybe try to copy /sitecore folder from a clean instance

Comment: Use a file diff tool to compare the directories between the deployed version and the development environment.  Also check region settings on the server are consistent with the development environment.  It really looks like something to do with languages - perhaps the user profile is set to use a Sitecore Shell Language that is not installed?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when the `client language` is not supported by Sitecore.

You can set the Clent Language in configuration.

```xml
<setting name="ClientLanguage" value="en-US" />
```

Read more on the subject here:
http://mhwelander.net/2013/05/30/language-settings-in-sitecore/

Comment: I had it set as '<setting name="ClientLanguage" value="en" />' that should be sufficient ? Problem still persists ...

Comment: I don't know why this would have happened, but you should be able to resolve it by clearing the cookies or by adding `sc_lang=en` to the url while in the Sitecore client