# JWPlayer Unexpected Token Ilegal

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I have the next test code, and I got the next error message

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

After that I got the next error message too

`Uncaught ReferenceError: jwplayer is not defined`

I've downloaded jwplayer from my account on the JWPlayer page. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js' type='text/javascript' ></script>
    <script src='./player/jwplayer.js' type='text/javascript' ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='target'>
    </div>

    <script language='JavaScript'>
      var playerInstance = jwplayer('target').setup({
        file:           './videos/jaguar.mp4',
        flashPlayer:    './player/jwplayer.flash.swf',
        widht:          600,
        height:         300,
        image:          './images/jaguar.jpg'
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure `jwplayer.js` is in the right location and the server is not seding some kind of `404` page? Is the file completely uploaded?

Comment: Yes, It is the first thing I check.

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719859/no-visible-cause-for-unexpected-token-illegal)?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you spelled `width` wrong.