# external javascript not running in Laravel 5

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

In Laravel 5, I set up a simple external js file inside `public/js/test.js`
It has one line of code:

`alert(1);`

I included the file like so in view:

`{{Html::script('js/test.js')}}`

When the page load, I got

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

error from that javascript file.

I tested running the same `test.js` file in my MAMP setup, and it run fine. So, the file has no issue. I cannot figure out what in Laravel 5 is causing the issue.

Please help.

Comment: unfortunately, i didn't use homestead. Do you know what I might be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the .js file into the public directory and call it with Laravel's `asset()` like so:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>`

If you are using it in view make the file name with `.blade.php` extension ex: `myjsfile.blade.php` and call it with an include in any of your view files

`@include('myjsfile.blade.php')`

Hope that helps

Comment: I've tried that. the js file is getting called. I think referencing to the file is not a problem. but i will try your suggestion with @include.

Comment: It will work for sure, just inside the `myjsfile.blade.php` start the file with `<script type="text/javascript">` and end the file with `</script>` and laravel will take that code and include it in the view that you want.

Comment: It will still give me an inline script, whereas I want to call an external script.

Comment: if you want an external script, you have to put your js file inside the public folder and then call it with this `<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>` that will get you an external script. Let me know if thats what youre looking for

Comment: I still get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" error. that did not solve it.

Comment: I thin you have issues in the actual javarscript file. Have a look at this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719859/no-visible-cause-for-unexpected-token-illegal

Comment: found a solution to my problem. Instead of running server with "php artisan serve", I now use MAMP server and run the project in the htdocs folder. I would have to move each file to this new project which is troublesome, but now I know I can call external js files. Thanks for your help all along.

Comment: Glad to hear that you found a solution! I use a WAMP server and never had any issues calling in outside files.