# Why is the semicolon 'unexpected'?

Tags: javascript

[image]

In [the above fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v0a7g8Le/), it says the semicolon at the end of the line is unexpected. How so?

```js
alert('foo');

alert('bar');
```

Comment: Your "semi-colon"  on the first line is actually a greek question mark.  Delete and retype it as a ; and the error will go away.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unexpected token ILLEGAL using node javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730548/unexpected-token-illegal-using-node-javascript)

Comment: https://i.redd.it/qy7vniac12q01.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first character is not actually a semicolon, it's a [Greek question mark](https://graphemica.com/%CD%BE), `U+037E` / `&#894;` / `&#x037E;` / `%CD%BE`

Greek question mark: `;`

Semicolon: `;`

The difference is barely noticeable though.

This works:

```js
alert('foo');

alert('bar');
```

Comment: No reason to automatically assume this is a troll question.

Comment: Thanks, this code snippet worked

Answer (score 5):

The character you have there is not a semicolon (character code 59), but a ["Greek Question Mark"](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+037E), character code 894.

```js
console.log(';'.charCodeAt()); // Greek
console.log(';'.charCodeAt()); // Normal
```

Use the regular `;` semicolon instead.

Answer (score 1):

The character on the first line is not a semicolon, it's a Greek question mark.

`&#894;`