# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL when set data to input form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, drupal

i want to set a data to a input form

but she not working and when i open console i found this error
[image]

```
    <?php print_r($output);
foreach($output as $key=>$out) {
$produitname = $out['produitname'];
$produitnid  = $out['produitnid'];
$type        = $out['type'];
$imageUrl        = $out['image'];
} ?>

<?php  print render(node_view(node_load(131), 'full', NULL)); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
Drupal.behaviors.devenirClientform = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('.webform-component--produits-choisie>input').val('<?php echo $produitnid ?>');
            $('.webform-component--type-de-client>input').val('<?php echo $type ?>');
            $('.webform-component--contrat>input').val('<?php echo $imageUrl ?>');
        });
    }
};  
//
</script>
```

Comment: Dont use the second $this.val('the text').instead just write the 'text' in the first $this.val().try it and say what happens

Comment: can you show your code ?

Comment: he told me : 
Uncaught ReferenceError: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNSRTUVWXYZ is not defined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No visible cause for "Unexpected token ILLEGAL"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719859/no-visible-cause-for-unexpected-token-illegal)