# Why does this code throw ReferenceError: test is not defined?

Tags: javascript, unicode, language-design, language-features, referenceerror

```js
var te‌st = 1
console.log(test)
```

Try running this simple code. It gives error: `ReferenceError: test is not defined`, despite the fact that I defined that variable. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In the variable declaration, the variable name contains a [zero-width non-joiner (ZWNJ)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner) character (between `e` and `s`), which is invisible, because its width is equal to zero. However, ECMAScript specification allows this character as a part of variable name.

However, in the `console.log()` call, there is just `test`, without any special characters. Therefore, it throws Reference Error, because the variable name is `te<ZWNJ>st`, not `test`.

Fortunately, there's an easy way to check if a variable name contains such characters. You can paste your code into JS Bin or JS Fiddle — they denote  these characters with a white dot on a red background. That's how it looks like in JS Fiddle:

[image]

I think there are also similar features in some IDEs.

<sub>Side note: this is an interesting way to prevent people from copy pasting the code snippets you use in answers into their own code. Consider the following code snippet:</sub>

```js
// Warning: non-copy-pastable, it won't work if you copy it into your code.
function a‌dd(a, b) {
  return a + b
}

console.log(a‌dd(2, 3))
```

<sub>There's a ZWNJ character in the function name and the function call, so it works here. However, if someone copied the function into their code and then manually typed `console.log(add(3, 4))`, it would throw `ReferenceError: add is not defined`.</sub>

<sub>Please don't take the above seriously, it's rather a joke than a practical use.</sub>

#### Related

- [What characters are valid for JavaScript variable names?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1661197/3853934)
- [No visible cause for “Unexpected token ILLEGAL”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12719859/3853934)