# Using Node to open index.js throws error

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I have not used Node before, but have setup an Apache localhost.

In my directory, I have index.js which reads

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('<h1>Hello world</h1>');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

and a package.json which requires Express.js.

In the command line, I cd into the workspace and run `node index.js`. But it does not open the server and instead throws this error. [image]

What needs to be done to produce a local server listening on port 3000? 
Node version is 6.7.0, express is 4.15.2. Running on Windows 10.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719859/no-visible-cause-for-unexpected-token-illegal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your text editor *may* be inserting some unsupported (non-UTF8) BOM in your index.js. Try adjusting your text editor preferences/settings to either instead include a UTF-8 BOM or remove BOMs entirely (node will read the javascript file as UTF-8 no matter what).