# Odd Unexpected Identifier encountered

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

As you can see, there is an odd A symbol in the angular-datatables code. But when I view the file outside of the browser it does not actually exist. What am I missing?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps this would give an explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719859/no-visible-cause-for-unexpected-token-illegal Did you try removing those characters and then running your script?