# Hidden characters in javascript after save

Tags: javascript, docker, nginx, docker-compose, gunicorn

Similar to [this unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45280790/hidden-characters-u0-added-to-file-after-save-on-server).

I have an app running in a docker container using `docker-compose`, served by nginx.  The front-end scripts are compiled using `gulp` into a `build.js` file.

The first time I bring up the docker container, there is no problem with `build.js`. Most times the build file is *re-created* (I rebuild constantly during development), Chrome finds a string of `\u0` characters at the end of `build.js`, causing it to throw the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`.

Sometimes when `build.js` is re-created, a handful of characters are missing from the version of `build.js` served to the browser:

`build.js`, local version:

```
var AnalyticsMixin = require('../mixins/AnalyticsMixin.vue');
```

`build.js`, browser version

```
var AnalalyticsMixin.vue');
```

This is in addition to the long string of repeated `\u0`s at the end of the file.

I also have a `gulp` task that minifies `build.js` and appends a hash of the contents to the filename (filename changes with each new save). Each new file here throws no error.

In another possible twist, this problem only reared it's head when we moved from a flask back-end to gunicorn.

These characters don't seem to be in the file itself - the version I can see in the inspect window in Chrome is one line longer than my local file.

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23487194/5799673), I tried setting `sendfile off;` in my `nginx.conf`. Nothing changed.

Could it have something to do with my `docker-compose` set-up? Something else in nginx?

#### Added:

This is the file that loads `build.js` (or the minified version). The name of the file is injected by gulp into `index.html` between the two comments `inject:js` and `endinject`

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app" ><router-view></router-view></div>

  <!-- inject:js -->
  <script src="/js/build.js"></script>
  <!-- endinject -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please post the `html`(at least with headers without body) which loads `build.js`.

Comment: @NanduKalidindi Added index.html

Comment: Can you try adding `<meta charset="UTF-8">` after the `head` tag? I bumped into a similar situation and this helped. Let's see if it works for you as well.

Comment: @ edbbishop did you try adding this meta tag to your html?

Comment: @NanduKalidindi - I did try that but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this by creating separate `Dockerfile`s for development and production - the one for development uses flask's server. `gunicorn` seems to be the culprit, but only when re-creating & serving `build.js` with new content, which isn't a problem for production.

`Dockerfile` uses only flask's default development server:

```
FROM python:3
ENV MODE dev
EXPOSE 8080

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y freetds-dev

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN python3 setup.py install
CMD python3 manage.py dev
```

`Dockerfile_prod`, using the gunicorn server

```
FROM python:3
ENV MODE dev
EXPOSE 8080

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y freetds-dev

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN python3 setup.py install
CMD gunicorn -w 3 -b 0.0.0.0:8080 wsgi
```

To build images using `Dockerfile_prod` instead of the default `Dockerfile`:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile_prod
```