# SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16) at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)

Tags: node.js, maven, npm, node-modules

What I'm trying to do?

I'm trying to install npm in my project,
And executed the below command in my terminal, which internally has a `npm install` to starts npm installation.

```
`mvn clean install -Dmaster.build.node=master`
```

And also i tried directly executing the below command,

```
`sudo npm install`
```

I tried using the latest node version and also the version's >4
 and Current  node version **v10.1.0**

What issue I'm facing?

Below is the error which i got on executing the above commands,

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at /Users/tanveer/workspace/myApp/target/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/index.js:72:20
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at CachingRegistryClient.RegClient /Users/tanveer/workspace/myApp/target/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/index.js:50:42)
npm ERR! Darwin 17.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/tanveer/workspace/myApp/target/nodejs/bin/node" "/Users/tanveer/workspace/myApp/target/nodejs/bin/npm" "run" "full" "-loglevel" "warn" "--registry https://npm.apple.com"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3

npm ERR! /Users/tanveer/workspace/myApp/target/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/._access.js:1
npm ERR! (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Unexpected token ILLEGAL
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

Can someone please help on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No visible cause for "Unexpected token ILLEGAL"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719859/no-visible-cause-for-unexpected-token-illegal)

Comment: In error stack, it's pointing to the library file. Which we can't change or modify.

Comment: Try `npm update`

Comment: after `npm update` , Do you want me to proceed with this command - `mvn clean install -Dmaster.build.node=master`

Comment: I never used `mvn` :(
Try run your app after update

Comment: still i'm getting same error..